Access Violation in TClientDataSet.Locate() for Farsi/Persian field name with more than 16 characters
I have a table that has a field with a completely Farsi/Persian name. The length of the field name is 25 characters.
In Delphi 10.4 update 2, when I use the TClientDataSet object (ADOQuery -> DataSetProvider -> ClientDataSet) and execute the Locate() command on that field, an Access Violation message is displayed.
This is my test query :
select 123 as 'تست تست تست تست تست'
union all
select 123 as 'تست تست تست تست تست'
union all
select 123 as 'تست تست تست تست تست'

And these are the components that I have used :

And this is the command and the error resulting from the execution of the command(I remind you that ADOQuery is connected to DataSetProvider and ClientDataSet is connected to DataSetProvider) :

But, when I reduce the length of the field name to 16 characters, the problem is solved.
What is the problem?

Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].
